# Appropriate way to adjust p values for multiple comparisons of unrelated domains?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, structural-equation-modeling

Our dataset has 325 participants. Within each participant, we are looking at how 3 brain regions (ROIs) in each hemisphere (so right and left separately) are correlated with 10 cognitive domains. Furthermore, we are splitting the data into 4 age groups (adolescent, young, middle, older adults).

Is it appropriate to adjust p values by:

- multiplying times 4 (one for each age group) or
- to multiply by all factors (`4(age group) * 2(side of brain) *3(ROIs) * 10(cognitive domains)`)?
- or the total number of correlations conducted?

This is an example of one of many test outputs, where `X` is a `cognitive domain`, and `Y` is a `brain ROI for one side`. I would like to adjust for young adult's significant p value appropriately:
[image: output]

Would it be more appropriate to apply some regression or structural equation model instead? Overall, these are exploratory analyses to understand how each `ROI` is associated in relation to each `cognitive domain` across age groups.

Comment: There is too much age heterogeneity within the age intervals you defined.  And thinking of age as something to stratify on means that you are not borrowing any information across age, which results in a great reduction in your effective sample size.  Think about a unified analysis with appropriate age interaction terms, treating age as continuous.  This will result in fewer parameters to have to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

There are no firm guidelines about what constitutes a "family of tests" when controlling the familywise Type I error rate.  In some research contexts, it is an easy decision, such as when conducting a multiple-*df* test and following it up with 1-*df* tests that carve up the omnibus H_0 into smaller, more interpretable portions.  This situations was illuminated decades ago in the ANOVA context, when rejecting an omnibus H_0 that all group means were equal was followed up by multiple pairwise comparisons (or other contrasts).

Since you are conducting exploratory analyses, I would hesitate to describe these as "hypothesis tests".  The value of exploration is to generate, rather than confirm, hypotheses (although these are 2 ends on a continuum, not distinct categories of methodological approaches), and hopefully you would then test the generated hypotheses on new, independent data. To that end, you can use other statistics to flag comparisons of potential interest, such as effect sizes (e.g., standardized mean differences between  conditions that exceed 0.5 in absolute value).

But if you were conducting tests on data from a design such as this, I would use the same guiding principle for defining a "family" that is popular in (M)ANOVA.  Any time you calculate a single test statistic for an omnibus H_0 (e.g., a main effect of one design factor, or an interaction between 2 design factors) at a particular alpha level, you would want to control your error rate for any follow-up tests that carve that H_0 into more specific, focused comparisons, all the way down to pairwise contrasts.